# $http interceptor: redirect on auth failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I copied the following code from the web to work with JWT authorisation, but it does not work. In particular the `$location.path` command has no impact - the redirect does not take place. I also tried with `$state.go`, but that led to bigger errors. I don't fully understand what `$q` is referring to here, not what is waiting for the promise to unwind, but the issue is `$location.path` not taking the user back to the login screen (nor are the proposals below with respect to `$state` changes).

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    console.log("app.js: httpInterceptor caught authorisation status response");
                    delete $localStorage.token;
                    $location.path('/');  // to login page
                    // $state.go('login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

To test, I send a message that creates an server error, catch that in devtools on the way back, and then manually set `response.status = 403`. The redirect is clearly parsed but does not lead to the redirect. I can see that the login screen is put back on the screen, but is then immediately overwritten by a different view.

This is the factory $http ajax request. **Is it possible that the `deferred` `$q` I use here is interfering with that in the interceptor?**

```
    $http(httpObj)
    .success(function (response) {  // returns 0: mongo resto data, 1: wpserver report
        console.log("%s succesful, response: %s", method, response);

        if (!updateNotAdd) {
            Restos.data.restos.push(response[0]);  // add to local copy of data
        } else {
            // replace existing entry with new information
            var idxToReplace = _.findIndex(Restos.data.restos, function(r) {
                return r.qname === resto.qname;
            });
            // copy over all data from editor model to database
            _.assign(Restos.data.restos[idxToReplace], resto);
        }

        var response = {
            success: true,
            id: response[0]._id,
            message: response[1]
        };

        $rootScope.$broadcast("ajaxresponse", response);
        deferred.resolve(response);
    })
    .error(function (msg) {
        // console.log(msg);
        var response = {
            success: false,
            message: msg
        };
        $rootScope.$broadcast("ajaxresponse", response);
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: looks like you need to run digest cycle after `$location.path('/');` then do `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: don't think so as `$scope` is not accessible from the `.config` method

Comment: ohh..thats my bad..you should do it `$rootScope`..for getting `$rootScope` you need to add `$injector` dependency in function & then inside your `responseError` function you could use `var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'); $location.path('/'); rootScope.$apply()`

Comment: i'm getting an error that a digest is already underway. As this is all part of $http, I did rather think that an $apply would not be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have an issue leveraging ui-router here. You need to use the `$injector` service to get a reference on the `$state` service. Observe the following change...

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location, $localStorage, $injector) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    console.log("app.js: httpInterceptor caught authorisation status response");
                    delete $localStorage.token;
                    $injector.get('$state').go('login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

The bigger issues you're experiencing are caused by a circular dependency due to ui-router injecting `$http` into `$TemplateFactory` - leading to a circular reference to `$http` inside `$httpProvider` when you attempt to inject `$state` (which doesn't yet appear to be in your `interceptors` injection signature anyways)

Comment: no error now, but redirect either. I've added more code in the original question to see if there is some other interference

Comment: @SimonH do you hit your `console.log("app.js: ...`?.. Try swapping `.go()` for `('$state').transitionTo('login');`

Comment: Yes, the the `console.log` is being hit, but the redirect does not take place and the server error is passed back to the original page via the `.error` function in the second code snippet

Comment: @SimonH dang.. I'm drawing a blank. I can't see why the state is not transitioning for you. Can you keep me posted with your findings? Also, try to bind to `$stateChangeError` in your `.run` block to see if we can find anything else out e.g. `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ ... })`

Comment: OK, I found it. I was not deleting enough authoirsation information when I got th e401 code so the controller of my auth view was logging me back in again automatically - duh!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you want to use, but probably this would redirect:

```
$window.location.href = url;
```